# How to eval inside a Handlebars expression?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js, backbone-model

I have a backbone model returning something like this:

```
{
    language: "us",
    us: {
        title: "Gigs",
        subtitle: "Stay tune to my upcoming gigs"
    },
    br: {
        title: "Shows",
        subtitle: "Fique ligado na minha agenda"
    }
}
```

The `language` is being updated dynamically, so it will determinate which object I'm gonna print, using Handlebars. Usually I would do:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<h2>{{subtitle}}</h2>
```

But I need to do some kind of concat:

```
<h1>{{language.title}}</h1>
<h2>{{language.subtitle}}</h2>
```

Of course this will not work. That's my question: How can I make the expression to be dynamically concat?

So that if the language is `"us"`, it calls:

```
<h1>{{us.language.title}}</h1>
<h2>{{us.language.subtitle}}</h2>
```

And if it's `"br"`, it calls:

```
<h1>{{br.language.title}}</h1>
<h2>{{br.language.subtitle}}</h2>
```

Comment: You can register a concat helper like [this](https://gist.github.com/adg29/f312d6fab93652944a8a1026142491b1) for example

Answer (score 2):

One of the best approaches both from an execution and good design standpoint might be to have a function on your model

```
model.currentLanguage = () => model[model.language]
```

Then you can use it in your views

```
<h1>{{currentLanguage().title}}</h1>
<h2>{{currentLanguage().subtitle}}</h2>
```

Answer (score 2):

When rendering, just use the right language data as the template's context.

```
this.template(this.model.get(this.model.get('language')));
```

You could also make a function on the model, unlike what [George mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44212670/1218980), not on the context directly.

```
var LanguageModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    /**
     * Get the translated data for the currently set language.
     * @param  {string} [lang] optional language string to override the default one
     * @return {Object} the language translation object.
     */
    getLanguageData: function(lang) {
        return this.get(lang || this.get('language'));
    },
    //...
});
```

And now, you only have to call that function to get the right object.

```
this.template(this.model.getLanguageData());
```

And in your template, there's no distinction:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<h2>{{subtitle}}</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `with` helper in Handlebars along with either a function like @George Mauer suggested or a local function while passing parameters in the template

Suppose we have a function returning the current language

```
var lang = model[String(model.language)]; // or this, depending on where your model lives
```

you would pass the `lang` variable in your template (depending on how you implement Handlebars templates in your application there are many ways)

in your template you'd have

```
{{#with lang}}
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <h2>{{subtitle}}</h2>
{{/with}}
```